# Xamarin layout designer error for support controls

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Controls from support design libs not showing on layout designer preview.

[image: Error]

"Show Error" button doesn't do anything

Here is my axml source

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  
   android:id="@+id/viewpager"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"         
  android:layout_height="match_parent"         
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> 
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And some exceptions from xamarin logfile

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems.ExceptionCalloutButton.CreateExceptionPopoverContent() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems\ExceptionCalloutButton.cs:line 55    at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems.ExceptionCalloutButton.ShowExceptionPopover() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems\ExceptionCalloutButton.cs:line 45    at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems.ExceptionCalloutButton.OnShowErrorButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.VisualItems\ExceptionCalloutButton.cs:line 32    at Xamarin.Designer.VisualItem.OnClicked() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer\VisualItem.cs:line 692    at Xamarin.Designer.VisualItems.ButtonItem.OnClicked() in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.VisualItems\ButtonItem.cs:line 84    at Xamarin.Designer.VisualItem.OnButtonReleased(ButtonEventArgs args) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer\VisualItem.cs:line 674    at Xamarin.Designer.DesignerSurface.ReleaseButtonOnItem(VisualItem vi, ButtonEventArgs args) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer\DesignerSurface.cs:line 590    at Xamarin.Designer.DesignerSurface.OnButtonReleased(ButtonEventArgs args) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer\DesignerSurface.cs:line 609    at Xamarin.Designer.DesignerSurface.ButtonReleased(ButtonEventArgs args) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer\DesignerSurface.cs:line 571    at Xamarin.Designer.Windows.EventUtils.ForwardButtonEvent(Action1 action, Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\EventUtils.cs:line 22
at Xamarin.Designer.Windows.WpfSurfaceRenderer.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.b__4(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) in C:\d\lanes\4471\3f99c5a7\source\xamarinvs\External\md-addins\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\WpfSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 586
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

UPDATE: I added all support design library packeges from nuget

Comment: Where is your xml code for button?

Comment: @Yupi i dont have button in my layout. This button draws by xamarin

Comment: `NullReferenceException` says that you are trying to preforme some action on something in this case button which isn't there. So etheir your button doesn't exist in layout or your id is wrong.

Comment: did you add the nuget packages for support library?

Comment: @ Yupi i know what `NullReferenceException ` means. I said you that is NOT my button. NOT!, i dont have axml code for it in my layout file. This button is xamarin's one.

Comment: @ HeisenBerg yes i added latest versions of pakages from nuget

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem is that support controls can render only when appcompat theme selected in layout designer window.